# Not able to make enclosure in DesignModeller

Tags: mechanical-engineering, cad, ansys, ansys-workbench

I have a Fusion 360 model that I imported into ANSYS Workbench Fluent as a .step file. I want to make an enclosure around it but it is giving me an error. The error doesn't occur if I choose just any one body as target body for enclosure. I don't understand what is going wrong since I am a beginner. [image: \Fusion 360 Model][image: Enclosure Details]
[image: Error]